# IntelliJ editor showing incorrect errors, using JavaFX

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

I'm using JDK 13.0.2 and JavaFX SDK 15.0.1, these errors don't show up in two of my friends who are using also the same versions.
JDK is located on C:\Java along with JavaFX and their path is shown correctly in the IntelliJ settings.
The program compiles and runs without any code errors.

[image: Screenshot of the errors]
[image: Library of JavaFX]
[image: VM Options]

Comment: Can you share the image of the external libraries you're using?

Comment: no screenshots of text, please ..

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues that happen very, very often when using JavaFX on a new Project (which I assume you do since you don't have any other new file than SlideController.java)

Have you added JavaFX as a library in your project structure ?

Have you correctly set up your virtual machine ?

To add JavaFX as a library in your project structure : Press "ctrl + alt + shift + s" or go to file > project structure. Then, go to libraries, hit the + icon, select Java and go to the lib folder in your JavaFX directory (you should have the bin, legal and lib files inside your JavaFX directory). Once selected, press OK, press OK again (you should only have one possible choice for the module), and press OK one last time. This should have added JavaFX as a library and you should be able to import everything from there on.

To set up your virtual machine : go to the top right corner and click on "Main" (you seem to have one configuration already, but if not it might also be written "Add Configuration..."). You can edit your actual configuration or add a new one by hitting the + icon and selecting "Application". According to your packages, find the Main class that you want to run (there is a Main class bar where you can add your main class name). Below that, in the VM Options, add this :

```
--module-path path\to\JavaFX\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.media
```

Where path\to\JavaFX\lib should be your own path to the lib file in your JavaFX directory (yes, the one that we added as library in the project structure). You don't actually have to add javafx.media in the very beginning, but you will have to at some point if you start using medias such as audio.

Now, you should be ready to run the Main.java file by right clicking it and clicking "Run Main" or by pressing "ctrl + shift + F10". Don't forget to check that your packages and imports are working properly.

If it still doesn't work, feel free to ask more questions, I'd be glad to help you out.

Comment: minor issue: you added controls twice :)

Comment: I have done both of those as I followed the steps my other friends had done as well.

Comment: what was the oucome ?